# What are my option to add links inside a PDF (I am using Linux)?

Tags: linux, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I want to add link into a PDF. I think this can be done easily with Acrobat (I have not try Acrobat myself but every Google searches point me there).

There are some web application options, but they add an ugly square above my PDF as a link. I don't want that.

Not necessarily to be opensource (but preferably free to use), what are my options?

Comment: You can use this online [editor](https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor) to insert links. Its use however has [limits](https://www.lifewire.com/best-free-pdf-editors-4147622)

Answer (score 4):

As *spike_66* suggested in [the comment above](https://superuser.com/questions/1304189/what-are-my-option-to-add-links-inside-a-pdf-i-am-using-linux#comment1937476_1304189), you can use [Sejda](https://www.sejda.com)'s [Online PDF editor](https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor) (or the [desktop version](https://www.sejda.com/desktop)) to add links in your PDF.

https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor

The editor is free to use for files up to 50Mb and 200 pages. You get 3 free tasks ("saves") per hour, each hour, when using the online editor.

- Upload file (or select from Google Drive, Dropbox, URL)
- Click on the 'Link' top menu item
- Select with the mouse the rectangle area that should be clickable
- In the context menu that appears enter the URL for the link

At the moment internal links to other pages inside the same document cannot be added, but this feature is likely coming soon.

[image: How to add links using Sejda's PDF editor]

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully used Sejda to add links to a file.  Had to use the web version because although the installation of sejda-desktop_7.1.6_amd64.deb succeeds, I get a run-time error:
"A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Error: There is no built binary for font-manager".  The web version seems easy enough to use.